# sigsuspend(), replace set or add?

Tags: c, linux, signals

As per the man page of sigsuspend(), it will replace the current signal mask set with its 1st parameter. In APUE, I saw an example as follows. The code maybe a little too long but I don't want to miss anything.

```
int pr_mask(char *s)
{
    sigset_t sigset;

    sigprocmask(0, NULL, &sigset);

    printf("%s: ", s);

    if(sigismember(&sigset, SIGINT)) printf("SIGINT ");
    if(sigismember(&sigset, SIGQUIT)) printf("SIGQUIT ");
    if(sigismember(&sigset, SIGUSR1)) printf("SIGUSR1 ");
    if(sigismember(&sigset, SIGALRM)) printf("SIGALRM ");
    /* ..... */

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void sig_quit(int signo)
{
    pr_mask("in sig quit");
}

int main()
{
    sigset_t new, old, tempset;

    signal(SIGQUIT, sig_quit);

    sigemptyset(&tempset);
    sigaddset(&tempset, SIGINT);

    sigemptyset(&new);
    sigaddset(&new, SIGQUIT);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &new, &old);

    pr_mask("in critical section");
    /* critical section */

    sigsuspend(&tempset);
    pr_mask("after return form sigsuspend");

    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &new, NULL);
    pr_mask("program exit");

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
in critical section: SIGQUIT 
in sig quit: SIGINT SIGQUIT 
after return form sigsuspend: SIGQUIT 
program exit:
```

The problem is the second line. The `SIGQUIT` is still in the signal mask set.

Should it be only `SIGINT` as sigsuspend has already replaced the signal mask with `tempset`, which is set to `SIGINT` only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While executing the SIGQUIT handler, SIGQUIT itself is blocked.  This is to avoid re-entering the handler by accident...

From the [POSIX spec for sigaction](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) (which you really should use instead of `signal`):

> When a signal is caught by a signal-catching function installed by sigaction(), a new signal mask is calculated and installed for the duration of the signal-catching function (or until a call to either sigprocmask() or sigsuspend() is made). This mask is formed by taking the union of the current signal mask and the value of the sa_mask for the signal being delivered, and unless SA_NODEFER or SA_RESETHAND is set, then including the signal being delivered.

The [POSIX spec for signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) is a little less specific:

> When a signal occurs, and *func* points to a function, it is implementation-defined whether the equivalent of a:
>
> signal(sig, SIG_DFL);
>
> is executed or the implementation prevents some implementation-defined set of signals (at least including *sig*) from occurring until the current signal handling has completed.

So it is legal for the OS to simply add the signal to the mask for the duration of the signal-handling function, and apparently that is what Linux does.

Comment: However the OS does not reset the signal mask to the old one after the signal handling function is done. Is there a way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

because the output "in sig quit: SIGINT SIGQUIT " is printed while executing the SIGQUIT handler.it would add the SIGQUIT to the signal mask, that means the current mask become the union of &tempset and the SIGQUIT.